# Keystrokes to Enable External Display on Lenovo G555 bios

Tags: bios, vga, lenovo-laptop, keystrokes

My Lenovo G555 latop (AMD Chip, Windows 7) has lost power to the LCD. By power I mean the entire monitor does not turn on (not just the backlight). However, the laptop still works otherwise.

If you have a Lenovo G555 or similar model, can you please post ALL of the keystrokes needed to enter the BIOS and enable the VGA port?

Since I can't see what is going on, I can't get into Windows, and therefore can't use the Function Keys to enable VGA output. I need the keystrokes to do this from the boot process (BIOS). Thanks.

Comment: This laptop uses Phoenix BIOS if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Machine translation below:

> Before connecting the new monitor, remove the battery, unplug the
>   machine for 1 minute, press the following keys: press the
>   <kbd>Fn</kbd>+ <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> in that order

---

Comment: Will try when I get the chance